# after deleting a superuser, all its entries are deleted django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-admin

there are also recent actions in the admin panel, for example, after creating an article, an inscription appears there, saying that this user created such an article, but after deleting this user, this last action is also deleted

and I wish this last action was not deleted from the log

how should i implement this?

Answer (score 0):

This is because on the model `LogEntry` the field `user` is set to `CASCADE` when the user it links to is deleted. [Source code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/4ce59f602ed28320caf3035212cb4d1c5430da2b/django/contrib/admin/models.py#L45)

So you need to create a custom override for `"django.contrib.admin"`

Where you replace:

```py
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        models.CASCADE,
        verbose_name=_('user'),
    )
```

With:

```py
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        null=True,
        models.SET_NULL,
        verbose_name=_('user'),
    )
```